# Docker 20.10 Ubuntu 22.04 OCI runtime exec failed:

Tags: docker

When trying to run any command in a container (for instance `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/sh`), I get the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown
```

I have installed `docker` and `docker compose` from the default ppa.
I tried every advice in these threads [1](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/246) [2](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969) but it didn't help. Can somebody help me? What do I do, how do I debug this?

Everything was just fine at Ubuntu 20.04 but I had to reinstall it yesterday because of some fatal failure.

Comment: This looks like a runtime regression, and thus a bug - I'm getting the same error on most containers (which wasn't the case before). Please file a bug report at the appropriate place.

Comment: I imagine this bug was introduced with containerd 1.6.7, since [notes for v. 1.6.8](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/tag/v1.6.8) says: *"Welcome to the v1.6.8 release of containerd! The eighth patch release for containerd 1.6 fixes a regression in the release build binaries which limited the environments they could be run in."*

Comment: FYI [I've opened an issue](https://github.com/docker/containerd-packaging/issues/291), asking the Docker developers to bump containerd to 1.6.8 in the repos to fix the regression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested, and downgrading `containerd.io` to 1.6.6 does indeed restore the wanted functionality (until 1.6.8 is added to the Docker repos).

So do the following for a workaround until the release is fixed (only applicable if you have installed from the Docker repos - `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu` ):

Downgrade `containerd.io` to 1.6.6:

```
sudo apt install containerd.io=1.6.6-1
```

Mark `containerd.io` as "held" (until a proper version is released).

```
sudo apt-mark hold containerd.io
```

Show which packages are held:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

When 1.6.8 or later (fixed) version is released, unhold the package:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold containerd.io
```

And do a standard pacakge upgrade to upgrade to latest version:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If your containers do not restart automatically after a reload of `containerd` (controlled by each containers restart policy), restart each container manually with:

```
docker start <containerId>
```

Comment: Containerd 1.6.8 are now part of the Docker repos, which fixes this regression.

Comment: IMPORTANT: Also don't forget to restart your container, e.g: `docker stop <containerId> && docker start <containerId>`

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this - thanks!